# Dynamic XSLT - run transformation from web page instead of command line

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm migrating some simple reports from bash to XSL. The XSL doesn't use an XML doc, it loads `.txt` files and other XML files to query for the reports.

I'm currently running the XSL from the command line and outputting the results as a text file:

```
java -jar saxon9he.jar -s:xsl_example.xsl -xsl:xsl_example.xsl -o:xsl_results.txt
```

I'd like to have this run from a web page, so that when you load the web page, it runs the XSL and presents the results.

I know it can be done, but I don't know how to do it, or know enough to start trying to figure it out. The closest I got was a chapter in a 2005 book titled "Beginning XSLT 2.0 - From Novice to Pro" which referred to "Dynamic XSLT", but the techniques are dated and only support XSLT 1.0 and I'm using 2.0.

I don't have server access so I'm looking for a client side solution.

Any suggestions? Clearly I am an XSL novice. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers only support XSL 1.0, so you'd need some sort of Javascript XSLT processor to do it on the client side, like http://www.saxonica.com/ce/index.xml or http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/

Of course, that means you have to expose all of it, including your raw data (the text and XML files), to the web, too. Just sayin'

Comment: thanks - re: data that's okay it's all public domain

Comment: have you used Saxon-JS yourself? I can export the xsl in the format it wants using Oxygen but I can't seem to make the tool work from the html page

Comment: If you're having trouble getting Saxon-JS working, then we can help you provided we know exactly what you're doing and exactly how it's failing. It's probably worth raising a new question tagged saxon-js. You're also welcome to use the official Saxonica support site at saxonica.plan.io.